# global variable says undefined - js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, global-variables

i'm trying to get some data and store them in an array. when i do this, that works fine and shows the result in $.each inside $.getJSON but outside of that, says array elements are undefined. also when i log length of array inside of $.each , it says 0. i even changed array name but no change. why this behaves like that?
Thanks!

```
var topping  = [];
$.getJSON(getUrlPizza, function(result){
            keepGetData = result;
            var j,k =0;
            $.each(keepGetData, function(i,field){
                getUrlTopping = urlTopping + "/" + keepGetData[i].id;
                $.getJSON(getUrlTopping, function(resultT){
                    topp = resultT;
                    $.each(topp, function(t,fieldT){
                        topping[j] = topp[t];
                        console.log(topping[j]); //it shows data
                        console.log(topping.length); // says 0
                        j++;

                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in `var` line because variable j is defined in scope but never assigned. Change that line to

```
var j = 0,k = 0;
```

or better use `topping.push()`!

Answer (score 0):

result parameter must be empty. put a dubugger on this line keepGetData = result; and watch for result in console window of your browser. result must be empty. then look from where you are passing this